# Pointcut or Aspect Around All Service Methods with Annotation @Transactional(readOnly = false)

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, pointcut

Is it possible to use Spring AOP or AspectJ to intercept all Service methods (contained in classes in the `com.app.service.*` package) having the annotation

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
```

(other elements possible as well in Spring's `@Transactional` annotation, but we only care about `readOnly = false`).

I could only find examples pertaining to pointcuts with simple Annotations, or `@Annotation(value)`.

My preference would be to use straight Spring, if possible.

It would probably be something like the below, but not sure about the syntax.

`@Around("execution(* com.app.service..*.*(..))" && @Transactional[??])`

Comment: That should be possible. I've worked sometime back on spring and I remember using a xml configuration to achieve the same. We used to mark all transactions as read only and explicitly configure required ones to be able write.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately no easy way to do that. Even when we have an Annotation-based pointcut, e.g.

```
@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class WriteTransactionAspectBean {

    @Before("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public void test(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional t) {
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }

}
```

the issue is the Annotations aren't our own, they come from an external JAR (Hibernate). This would require Load-Time Weaving or some other difficult workaround.

[Aspectj: intercept method from external jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292352/aspectj-intercept-method-from-external-jar)

But to make things even worse, Annotations need `RetentionPolicy=RUNTIME` in order to be "discovered" by Pointcuts. And we would need to go thru every method and add this specification to every `@Transactional`. There's no way to automatically make all `@Transactional`'s Runtime-retainable in the application.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. The `@Transactional` annotation is defined with runtime scope as you can clearly see in the corresponding [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html). Otherwise Spring could not do anything with it either.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a pointcut like this:

```java
execution(@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(readOnly = false) * com.app.service..*.*(..))
```

Comment: The issue I came across with this one is, I had to get a `Transactional t` argument to examine the object. And whenever I had this argument, the app wouldn't start (there was an error). It worked when I had a simple signature, without the actual `Transactional t` object.

Comment: I do not understand what you just wrote.