# Problem with AOP/AspectJ not executing on criterion

Tags: spring, hibernate, aop, aspectj, aspect

Does anyone know why the following AOP/AspectJ doesn't work in Examples **2,3** ?

Note: **Example 1 works**.

My goal is to intercept the firing of Hibernate [Query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html)'s `executeUpdate()`, which occurs throughout the application. Hibernate Query is an interface, and I see in the code that the implementing class I get back  is [QueryImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/impl/QueryImpl.html). So that is the class I want to target, although I've tried generic filters too.

XML

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="myAspect" ref="aspectBean">

       <!-- EXAMPLE 1: SIMPLE TEST: WORKS OK. 
            I intercept all methods in all my custom classes in "dao" package. -->
        <aop:pointcut id="test1" expression="execution(* myapp.dao.*.*(..))" /> 
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="test1" method="doTest1" /> 

       <!-- EXAMPLE 2: DOESN'T WORK.
            Target everything in Hibernate's Impl package with executeUpdate() function -->         
        <aop:pointcut id="executeUpdate2" expression="execution(* org.hibernate.impl..*..executeUpdate(..))" />
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="executeUpdate2" method="handleExecuteUpdate" /> 

        <!-- EXAMPLE 3: DOESN'T WORK.
            Target QueryImpl specifically -->   
        <aop:pointcut id="executeUpdate3" expression="execution(* org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(..))" /> 
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="executeUpdate3" method="handleExecuteUpdate" /> 

    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
<bean id="aspectBean" class="myapp.util.AOPAspect">
</bean>
```

I know for a fact the Hibernate hierarchy is correct. Example #1 works great so I know the AOP/AspectJ is wired properly. Is there something about external library traversal that doesn't support AOP/AspectJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it doesn't work because I'm dealing with an external JAR (in this case, Hibernate). Example 1 works because I'm within my own code.

No easy solutions for external JAR pointcuts, only Load-Time Weaving is possible (but I haven't tried it),

[Aspectj: intercept method from external jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292352/aspectj-intercept-method-from-external-jar)

Comment: Good that you found the root cause of your problem. Besides, using LTW **is** easy.